# MongoDB: update from ObjectId to string for many documents

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I have a complex structure similar to:

```
{
    type: "Data",
    data: [
      "item1": {...},
      "item2": {...},
      ...
      "itemN": {
          "otherStructure": {
              "testData": [
                  {
                      "values": {...}
                  },

                  {
                      "values": {
                          "importantKey": ObjectId("23a2345gf651")
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
    ]
}
```

For such kind of data structure I want to update data type for all these `importantKeys` from ObjectId into string.

I was trying queries similar to:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{type:"Data"},
{$toString: "data.$[element].otherStructure.testData.$[element].values.importantKey"},
{"data.element.otherStructure.testData.element.values.importantKey": {$type: "objectId"}})
```

But all these tries were no successful.

So, are there any adequate solutions for updating such data?

**UPDATE**
Sorry for confusing, my structure is more complex:

```
data.content.$[element].otherStructure.testData.keys.$[element].values.$[element].meta.importantKey
```

All these `$[element]` elements means objects with list of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this workaround:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.content": {
        $map: {
          input: "$data.content",
          as: "data",
          in: {
            otherStructure: {
              testData: {
                keys: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$data.otherStructure.testData.keys",
                    as: "testData",
                    in: {
                      "values": {
                        $map: {
                          input: "$$testData.values",
                          as: "values",
                          in: {
                            "meta": {
                              "importantObject": {
                                "importantKey": {
                                  $toString: "$$values.meta.importantObject.importantKey"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
{$out:"collection"}
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GJH0_MjJ2zd)

Comment: But if some of the documents with similar structure don't have this property, it'll insert it instead just updating data type for existing properties?

Comment: @pythonista No, `$map` will stop execution if there is no any nested array with expected structure. You try to force wrong structure and check if it updates correctly

Comment: How the second `element` is handled here? I have a little bit more complex structure and is trying to understand all the details here. (Updated structure in original post)

Comment: @pythonista share your sample data here https://mongoplayground.net/p/wcRk9m2_7_N

Comment: I updated your configuration section.https://mongoplayground.net/p/PbZWE8-O7vO

Comment: @pythonista check again please, I've updated my answer

Comment: it works! Btw, is it possible to save other properties from "importantObject"?  Cause type of "importantKey" has been updated but other properties are removed

Comment: @pythonista sure, you may add / remove keys

Comment: I don't want to remove existing keys, just update type of this one field. Other keys should be as they are.

Comment: Is is possible to use $ROOT here somehow, etc.?

Comment: @pythonista Post here what are you trying to do. Or post new ticket to get answered

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/soxHSUBpxH4 I just added a few more keys "near" importantKey. They shouldn't be affected by this query. Only ObjectId should be changed to str with appropriate value.

Comment: @pythonista take a look https://mongoplayground.net/p/NQwWk8hX3G2